# mysqli doesn't return instance with die()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, return, die

I have function :

```
function dbConnect($usertype, $connectionType = 'mysqli') {

   // some code hare

   return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die ('Cannot open database');
}
```

but when I try this:

```
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM images');
```

function dosn't return anything and it say :

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpsols\mysql\mysqli.php on line 10**

but it works this way(without die())

```
return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[..] or die()` construct leads to funny behaviour in conjunction with the return statement: The whole thing is interpreted as a boolean expression.

And because `new mysqli` will never be false, the "die" is never processed, and thus, your function returns `true` instead of a newly created instance of `mysqli`.

If you still would like to use `or die()`, do this:

```
$result = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) ;
if (!$result) die ("Can't open database.");
return $result;
```

Comment: `new mysqli will never be false` what happens when connection fails?

Comment: you still get a new mysqli instance. a constructor will always return an object.

Comment: Wow. Too many a people have no idea on how mysqli actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function dbConnect($usertype, $connectionType = 'mysqli') {

   // some code hare
   try {
       return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
   } catch(Exception $e) {
       die ('Cannot open database');
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: It is imaginary one. You just got it right off your head, while never used it in real.

Comment: this code has any problem or not! if it has tell me what! this not important that I use it before or not!

Answer (score -2):

aside from this funny one-liner problem, your idea of error handling is all wrong. Sadly, it was copy-pasted to other answer as well.

Here is the right code

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() )
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_errno()." ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
return $mysqli;
```

Honestly, this `die ('something');` thing is a childhood disease of PHP. Time to grow up a little.

Comment: PHP is ridden with diseases like that. If you would like to grow up, stop using PHP and get into Java.

Comment: It is not  wand, it's a wizard, you know. One who helpless with PHP, won't make a fortune in java as well.

Comment: You can't tell people to grow up whilst still using PHP yourself. PHP is no language for grownups, we both know that. So stop being arrogant and start being constructive, or get into Java.

Comment: Being constructive, I believe, is to provide the right working solution. While being arrogant, mind you, is to provide a solution that never actually works yet trying to mentor other people what they have to say or do ;)